# header .png doesn't upgrade

Tags: header-image

I uploaded the new header image via ftp, when it used to take effect immediately, today the header stay the same. Even though I have erased the website and browser cache, but nothing changed. Please could you help me.
www.lesmininours.ca

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change this file from your ftp http://lesmininours.ca/wp-content/themes/kiddo-turf-parent/images/header_image.png

Also please check if you have an active cache plugin in your site. If you have one, you should clear your cache in your site, not in your browser.

Comment: I completed all these tasks, I mean, changing the file on ftp and erasing the cache through W3 Total Cache plugin, but still the header inchanged.

Comment: have you try to open it from different computer?

Comment: Yes. even on other computer, the header still inchanged